# VBA. How can I reference multiple sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

This is  my working code:

```
Set newwbk = Workboooks.Open(Newtext.Text)
Set newSheet = newwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set datawbk = Workboooks.Open(Datatext.Text)
Set dataSheet = datawbk.Worksheets("CAP", "RES")
```

I am having an error at the second line. Can anyone help me?

How can I reference the "Two sheets CAP and RES"?
What I am trying to do is compare the "datawbk" (which has multiple sheets) with another workbook, say "newwbk" (only one sheet), then for example if they have same input in D2, the whole row of D2 (A2, B2, C2, E2...) in "newwbk" will be filled up with what is written in "datawbk" A2, B2, C2, etc. respectively.

Comment: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: see if this helps [Link](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/sheets.htm)

Answer (score 0):

use `Set datasheet = Worksheets(Array("CAP", "RES"))` as in example below

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, datasheet As Object
    Set datasheet = Worksheets(Array("CAP", "RES"))
    For Each sh In datasheet
        Debug.Print sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub
```

output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it shows error on this part:
For iCol = 1 To dataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count